# Expression must have integral or enum type Char*

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, stdstring

I have a MFC project  which do something like this

CString getTimeString( void )
{
    SYSTEMTIME      systemTime;
    CString         datestr;

```
GetSystemTime( &systemTime );

datestr.Format( "%02i/%02i/%04i, %02i:%02i:%02i",
    systemTime.wDay, systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wYear,
    systemTime.wHour, systemTime.wMinute, systemTime.wSecond );

return ( datestr + "; " + get_file_info().PName.c_str() + ", " + get_version_info().PVersion.c_str() );
```

}

Now I replicating something like this in QT

```
char* getTimeString( void )
{
     QDateTime      systemTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
      QString       datestr  = systemTime.toString() ;



    /*GetSystemTime( &systemTime );

    datestr.Format( "%02i/%02i/%04i, %02i:%02i:%02i",
        systemTime.wDay, systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wYear,
        systemTime.wHour, systemTime.wMinute, systemTime.wSecond );

*/

    return ( datestr.toStdString().c_str() + "; " + get_file_info().PName.c_str() + ", " + get_version_info().PVersion.c_str() );
}
```

It throws an error
" Expression must have integral or enum type... "
ON closer Look I realise that since its not std::String we cannot add up like this ..
S o My question is how would I acheive return function in QT in exact same way as its done in VS2010( shown above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that in the following way:

```
[..]
return QString("%1; %2, %3")
               .arg(datestr)
               .arg(QString(get_file_info().PName.c_str()))
               .arg(QString(get_version_info().PVersion.c_str())).toLocal8Bit().data();
```

Comment: Hi eveyrone , I have  made the changes  as suggested by Vaqhancho but  I g get error like  :\mydir\application\libs\lib_know/FileVersioninfo.h(83): error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'know::FileVersionInfo::Pcalculator'
1>          Source or target has incomplete type
1>C:\mydir\application\libs\lib_know/FileVersioninfo.h(83): error C2548: 'know::init_file_version_info' : missing default parameter for parameter 1
1>MessagingInterface.cpp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'

Comment: Actually in other project the above function with CString works fine . I am wondering is it something to relate with QVariant?

Comment: I hav tried that as well before posting teh reply but it doesnt work. I have tried even something like this one QString convert(const std::string& s)
{
   return QString::fromStdString(s);
}

Comment: char* getTimestampString( void )
{
   QDateTime  systemTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
   QString    datestr    = systemTime.toString() ;

   return( QString("%1; %2, %3").arg( datestr )
                                .arg( convert( get_file_version_info().ProductName ) )
                                .arg( convert( get_file_version_info().ProductVersion ) ) 
                                 ) ;
  // return (" implement later");
 

  }

Comment: I have reposted my qs in different post ( as I thought its different problem ) and someone has suggested that "there is no overload of arg that takes a char*  but i didnt get what he meant by that line.

Comment: below are link of my new post                                                                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375642/cannot-convert-from-int-missing-default-parameter-for-parameter-1

Comment: @samprat, the error you got refers to `know::init_file_version_info` and not to the Qt stuff. What is that? Investigate why the compiler complains. On which function call?

Comment: Thanks mate for all the help you have given to me..  The issue is taht know::init_file_version_info is being used by lot of other projects running on vs2010 and in linux  and all these projects used the function which I have posted under vs2010 and they dnt throw any error , just to be on safe side I have compiled old projects and they seem to be working fine .. so I feel something is wrong on my prject.  I have commented by whole function and it stil throws error if I include those header files .. so may be something is wrong with inclusion of those header files

Comment: SOLVED !!!!!..  the  know::init_file_version_info was using some boost library which I have not included by using hit and trail method  It works now...