# cannot convert from int & missing default parameter for parameter 1

Tags: c++, qt, mfc, qstring

I am developing new project in Qt with existing MFC project . SO in MFC I have a function which uses SYSTEMTime  and return CString.

example

```
    CString getTimestampString( void )
{
    SYSTEMTIME      systemTime;
    CString         datestr;

    GetSystemTime( &systemTime );

    datestr.Format( "%02i/%02i/%04i, %02i:%02i:%02i",
        systemTime.wDay, systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wYear,
        systemTime.wHour, systemTime.wMinute, systemTime.wSecond );

    return ( datestr + "; " + get_file_version_info().ProductName.c_str() + ", " + get_file_version_info().ProductVersion.c_str() );
        // get_file_version_info  are in some other director under lib_know directory.
}
```

The above function compile in  VS2010.

Now doing same thing in QT

```
   QString getTimestampString( void )
{
   QDateTime        systemTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
      QString            datestr    = systemTime.toString() ;

   return( QString("%1; %2, %3").arg( datestr )
                                .arg( get_file_version_info().ProductName.c_str() )
                                .arg( get_file_version_info().ProductVersion.c_str() ) 
                                 ) ;

  }
```

I got following errors

```
  C:\mydir\application\libs\lib_know/FileVersioninfo.h(83): error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'know::FileVersionInfo::Pcalculator'
1>
```

Source or target has incomplete type

```
1>C:\mydir\application\libs\lib_know/FileVersioninfo.h(83): error C2548: 'know::init_file_version_info' : missing default parameter for parameter 1
```

PS -> I cant able to make any changes in lib_know as this library is being used by many other projects..

Please let me know where I am falling , I am completely clueless now.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: there is no overload of arg that takes a char*

Comment: @ratchetfreak , could you please elaborate .. I havnt understood much

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!!!!..  the  know::init_file_version_info was using some boost library which I have not included by using hit and trail method  It works now...  The interesting thing was that compiler was not throwing any linker error or anything related to boost functions

Comment: A compiler **never** throws linker errors. The linker is usually not invoked, if the compiler fails.